# As in the BEM methodology is better Nativity elements nested within elements

Tags: html, css, bem

As in the BEM methodology is better Nativity elements nested within elements
I have the following markup:

```
 <table class="product-list">
                        <tr>
                          <th>Your Items</th>
                          <th>Price</th>
                          <th>Qty</th>
                          <th>Remove</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <div class="product-list__wrapper-img"><img src="./images/mini-cart/1.jpg"></div>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
```

I have a block `.product-list`, it has the element `.product-list__wrapper-img` , in it there is a picture `<img src="./images/mini-cart/1.jpg">`
Stylizing the block I put

```
.product-list{
  width: 680px
}

.product-list__wrapper-img{
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  width: 77px;
  height: 90px
}

.product-list__wrapper-img img {
  position: absolute
  z-index: 1
  top: 50%
  left: 50%
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
  max-width: 98%
  max-height: 98%
}
```

I know that seems to be in the BEM to the tags contact is not desirable, i.e., so seems to be impossible to write

```
.product-list__wrapper-img img{
}
```

But what when give the img class to style it, and whether in the BEM , to be the element in the element.
I know that modificator can but the element I know.
I guess I need to call this picture 
`.product-list__img` maybe 
`.product-list__wrapper-img__img`
I would be glad for any help in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imho:

```
<table class="product-list">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="product-list__wrapper-img">
                <img class="product-list__img" src="./images/mini-cart/1.jpg">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

or:

```
<table class="product-list">
    <tr>
        <td class="product">
            <div class="product__wrapper">
                <img class="product__img" src="./images/mini-cart/1.jpg">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```